# Swagger ui endpoint view section is causing a newline after each character

Tags: c#, .net, swagger-ui, .net-5

When i navigate to the swagger ui when i run my dotnet application, each character is listed on a new line when viewing the ui. it causes the section to become extremely big. Can someone please help to fix the bug? I would like the formatting to be a normal one line string. I will attach an image below.

[image]

Comment: Do you see in error in browser console?

Comment: when I open the browser console, the following shows:

Could not load content for https://localhost:5001/swagger/swagger-ui.css.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Comment: fixed the issue by clearing history and cookies.

Comment: good, it worked for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to my problem was simply clearing history and cookies and restarting browser.

Comment: Have the same issue, but clearing history with cookies and restarting browser doesn't help